# When does a method warrant being defined in the Model instead of Controller? (from Chap 10 of Rails Tutorial)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I am currently going through Hartl's Rails Tutorial, and through the first 10 chapters or so have gotten used to the convention of putting most of the actions/methods in the controller.  Currently, as the book is going through and [defining a `feed` method](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts#sec-a_proto_feed) for the Microposts, the method is placed with the `User.rb` *model* instead.  As I am relatively new to the world of rails (and programming in general), I was wondering what the rationale or convention followed for putting this method (copied below) in the Model?

The method placed in the `User.rb` model:

```
  def feed
    # This is preliminary. See "Following users" for the full implementation.
    Micropost.where("user_id = ?", id)
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually quite some contention on what code to put where, but in general, there are some easy guidelines to follow.

Does the method have to know some detail about the underlying data structure? Put it in the model.

An easy way to determine this is when it uses ActiveRecord methods like find, where, or specific columns in the database. By keeping this logic in the model, that means if you need to change the underlying datastore, you only have to change the model.

Does the method have some say in how a page is going to be rendered? Put it in the controller.

Generally, controllers should be pretty thin, pushing data to views and saving form data back to models.

While (if I remember correctly) Hartl does not take about non-rails classes, don't be afraid to put 'business logic' outside of the rails structure. You can create a app/lib or app/services or app/x directory and put plain old ruby objects in there, which can then be called from your controllers and models to handle those things they are good at.

Answer (score 2):

Aim to 'push' things 'up' into the model as much as possible, then they will be repeated less and available to more.  Don't just use models for Active Record database tables.

You can often unit test models easier.

Another 'next' place to put stuff that is shared is in `/lib`